# Google Apps Start Page switched to iGoogle automatically

Tags: google-workspace

Using Google Apps for Education, over the summer our start page randomly changed itself to iGoogle, and we can no longer customize it.  Is there any way to change it back?  Or, how do I globally configure the iGoogle page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has been incrementally rolling out this change over the last few months, replacing the standard start page with iGoogle. I don't think there is any way to switch it back - the company wants you to use iGoogle. It is fairly customizable, although I don't know how it would be done at a global level.